# colab research google: How should i write the output of the jupyter notebook to my google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am writing a crawler for wikipedia and wish to write the populated results in a csv.
Is there anyway I can directly store the generated output of my program to a Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your google drive on the google colab instance using `google-drive-ocamlfuse` (https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse). For installing ocamlfuse and getting the necessary permissions run:

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

After this you will need to mount google drive to your instance using:

```
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

Now you should have all your google drive files in the `drive` folder. You can check using:

```
!ls drive
```

After this you can read or write any file to/from your google drive.

[1] https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d

Answer (score 0):

### Connect to Gdrive using below snippet.

You will have to authenticate twice using the link from cell output.

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}

!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

### Read CSV using pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('drive/path/file.csv')
```

### Save CSV

Use index = False if you don't need index as first col in csv.

```
df.to_csv('drive/path/file.csv',index = False)
```